# How do I convert (or shift) byte array {0x01, 0x02, 0x03} as {0x01, 0x23}?

Tags: c#

I have some byte strings up to 16 bytes long. On my GUI, a user inputs characters 0-9 into a textBox, it is converted to `byte[]`, concatenated with other arrays, and is written to the port.

Say the user enters an odd numbered code: "12345". My programs converts this to:
`{0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05}`. I need a way to shift odd numbered code arrays to this: `{0x01, 0x23, 0x45}`.

Say the user enters an even-numbered code: "1234". I would need the byte array to read as `{0x12, 0x34}`

This array is being written to a radio to program it and this is exactly how the radio needs the data sent.

Comment: your user entering hex i take it?

Comment: divide the number by 256

Comment: No sir, the user is entering an ASCII integer 0-9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
var input = "12345";
var working = input.PadLeft(input.Length + input.Length % 2, '0');
var result =
    Enumerable
        .Range(0, working.Length / 2)
        .Select(x => working.Substring(x * 2, 2))
        .Select(x => byte.Parse(x, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));
```

`working` ensures that the input text begins with a `0` if it has an odd number of characters.

The result is simply a paired of set of characters that are parsed as hex into bytes. Simple.

So `"12345"` becomes `{ 1, 35, 69 }` or `{ 0x01, 0x23, 0x45 }`.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. However, for "result" to be a byte array, i had to add .ToArray();

Answer (score 0):

Taking your question exactly how you specified it

```
public static byte[] SomethingFunky(byte[] bytes)
{
   var list = bytes.ToList();
   if (bytes.Length % 2 != 0)
      list.Insert(0,0);

   return Enumerable.Range(0, list.Count)
                    .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                    .Select(x => (byte)(list[x] * 10 + list[x + 1]))
                    .ToArray();
}
```

**Usage**

```
var input = "12345".Select(x => byte.Parse(x.ToString())).ToArray();
var list = SomethingFunky(input);
Console.Write(string.Join(", ", list));
```

**Output**

```
1, 23, 45
```

[Full Demo Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/E39rxC)